# Concurrency request problem in nodejs api: 100 request to join contest with 1 vacancy

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, concurrency, serverless

I'm working on node api, and facing concurrent request problem.

```
pseudo code
1. Get user details along with credit balance.
2. Get contest maxEntry count (1 user = 1 count), total no. user joined contest so far, maxEntryPerUser, and contest entry fee.
3. Compare user credit balance and entry if balance is low then throw error
4. Compare maxEntry and totalJoined, if maxEntry is less or equal to totalJoined then throw error and not allow user to join the contest otherwise allow.
```

**Problem 1: Suppose user have 2 credit balance and contest entryFee is 2, maxEntryPerUser is 1**

user have credit balance 1, and user sent 100 request concurrently, all 100 request started processing parallelly, out of 100 more than 50 request get process successfully i.e. same user joined the contest more than 50 time with low credit balance
Expected result: 99 request must get failed and only 1 request should get success response.

**Problem 2: Suppose maxEntry count 1**

Multiple users sent 100 request concurrently, all 100 request started processing parallelly, out of 100 more than 50 request get process successfully i.e. more than 50 users joined the contest whereas there was only 1 entry allowed
Expected result: 99 request must get failed and only 1 request should get success response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be solved by running the check and the data modification in the same `REPEATABLE READ` transaction. Then all but one transactions will get a serialization error and have to restart.

If you expect conflicts that often, it might be better to use `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE` in the check to ensure that only one check can run on the same data at the same time.